# Where is the "About Me" text stored in SP2013 databases

Tags: 2013

My boss has asked me to find out how many staff have not edited their user profiles in our SP 2013 site . We want to email those that have not!

Is the best plan to see who has not added any text into the "About me " field in their profile.

If so how do I find what table and field is that stored in?

many thanks for any assistance given.

Answer (score 2):

Please **don't touch the SharePoint database** to don't lose the Microsoft support and to avoid DB locks! for more details check my answer at [SharePoint 2013 list in SQL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226054/sharepoint-2013-list-in-sql/226057#226057)

**However,** you can get the `User Profile Properties` via code as the following:

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles;

namespace UserProfilesCSOM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Replace the following placeholder values with the target SharePoint site and
            // target user.
            const string serverUrl = "http://serverName/";  
            const string targetUser = "domainName\\\\userName";  

            // Connect to the client context.
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(serverUrl);

            // Get the PeopleManager object and then get the target user's properties.
            PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
            PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(targetUser);

            // Load the request and run it on the server.
            // This example requests only the AccountName and UserProfileProperties
            // properties of the personProperties object.
            clientContext.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var property in personProperties.UserProfileProperties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", 
                    property.Key.ToString(), property.Value.ToString()));
            }
            Console.ReadKey(false);

            // TODO: Add error handling and input validation.
        }
    }
}
```

**Via REST**

You can use `GetUserProfilePropertyFor` function to get **About Me** Property

```
var theData = {
 "propertiesForUser": {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser" }, 
    "accountName": "i:0#.f|membership|vardhaman@tsunami684.onmicrosoft.com",
    "propertyNames": ["PreferredName", "Department"]
     }
};

var requestHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
};

jQuery.ajax({
    url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertiesFor",
    type:"POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(theData),
    contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(jqxr,errorCode,errorThrown){
        console.log(jqxr.responseText);
    }
});
```

**For more Details check :**

- [How to: Retrieve user profile properties by using the .NET client object model in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-retrieve-user-profile-properties-by-using-the-net-client-object-model-in)
- [SharePoint 2013: Get UserProfile Properties with REST API](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was not able to run the c~ soloution so I ran this powershell instead and dumped it to a spread sheet and was able to see the blank "About Me "  fields http://www.rigelgroupllc.com/blog/2013/10/14/export-sharepoint-user-profiles-to-csv/